# Angular 6 | Express : Getting 404 error on dist files

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular6

Thanks for taking the time to read my question. My website works fine when I run ng serve. When I run ng build --prod, that works fine as well. Problem is, when I try to render index.html in dist im getting 404 errors. The errors are 404 errors for my main, styles, and polyfill files. I'm trying to build a back end so that I can process card payments. Any help would be appreciated - have been knocking my head against the wall for hours now with no resolve. This is my code below:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

server.listen(2000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on 2000..')
});
console.log(__dirname);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/culture/index.html');
});
```

src/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Culture</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

dist/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Culture</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aaf8a2468e47be90b64b.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.b4daf421c94934f530d4.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.36d7357da7cc32c08c65.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Again, in short, localhost is giving 200 code which is good it means its connecting to the right place. The problem is once it is connected it can not find any files. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must correct this line of code: `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` to something like this: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/culture')));` if your Angular app files are in `dist/culture` directory.

Main problem is that when your `index.html` for example tries to load `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` it uses request to path `http://localhost:2000/favicon.ico`. Your `express` backend have defined static assets on `__dirname` and your actual app is in `dist/culture` so your request should look like `http://localhost:2000/dist/culture/favicon.ico`.

Applied change has improved configuration of static files location.

Comment: ahh, thank you. This answer is perfect and perfectly resolved my problem. You also taught me something new. Now I will look up what it actually does. But it works. Cheers